# Have a null check on Model but still getting Null object reference ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

**controller**

```
public ActionResult EditProduct(int id)
{
     ProductViewModel ViewModel = new ProductViewModel();         
     ViewModel.SingleProduct = DB.Prouducts.Where(x => x.ProductID == id).FirstOrDefault();
     ViewModel.ImageList = DB.ImageGalleries.Where(x => x.ProductIdFk == id).ToList();
     return View(ViewModel);
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditProduct(Prouduct product, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> thumb, ImageGallery images)
{
        CategoryDropdown();
        BrandDropdown();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {       
            HttpPostedFileBase Image1 = thumb.FirstOrDefault();        
                product.ProductSlug = slug;
                var userID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"]);
                product.UserIdFk = userID;
                DB.Entry(product).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                DB.SaveChanges();
                int LastInsertedID = product.ProductID;
                foreach (var tmb in thumb)
                {
                    if (tmb != null)
                    {
                        string FileName = tmb.FileName;
                        string Extenstion = Path.GetExtension(FileName);
                        if (Extenstion.ToLower() == ".jpeg" | Extenstion.ToLower() == ".jpg" | Extenstion.ToLower() == ".png" | Extenstion.ToLower() == ".webp")
                        {
                            FileName = FileName + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff") + Extenstion;
                            string ImageSavePath = Server.MapPath("/Content/Assets/Photos/");
                            tmb.SaveAs(Path.Combine(ImageSavePath + FileName));
                            string ThumbSavePath = Server.MapPath("/Content/Assets/Photos/Thumbs/");
                            ThumbGenration.ResizeStream(522, tmb.InputStream, Path.Combine(ThumbSavePath + FileName));
                            images.ImageName = FileName;
                            images.ImageThumb = FileName;
                            images.ProductIdFk = LastInsertedID;
                            //var userID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"]);
                            images.UserIdFk = userID;
                            DB.ImageGalleries.Add(images);
                            DB.SaveChanges();
                            TempData["Success"] = "Data Added Successfully!";
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
       return View();
    }
```

**View**

```
@model  RentalServices.Models.ProductViewModel


 @using (Html.BeginForm("EditProduct", "Product", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SingleProduct.ProductID);
<div class="add-item-wrapper">
    <h4>Listing Details</h4>
    <hr class="noPadMar" />
    <div class="add-item">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-group">
                    @*<label class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 control-label">Title</label>*@
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SingleProduct.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-sm-3 col-md-3 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        @*<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="TITLE" />*@
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SingleProduct.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SingleProduct.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SingleProduct.Price, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-sm-3 col-md-3 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SingleProduct.Price, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SingleProduct.Price, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-group">
                    @Html.Label("CATEGORY", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-sm-3 col-md-3 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SingleProduct.CategoryIdFk, ViewBag.CategoryDropdown as SelectList, "CHOOSE CATEGORY", new { @class = "form-control", id = "CategoryID" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SingleProduct.CategoryIdFk, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="hide">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-group">
                        @Html.Label("BRAND", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-sm-3 col-md-3 control-label" })
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SingleProduct.BrandIdFk, ViewBag.BrandDropdown as SelectList, "CHOOSE BRAND", new { @class = "form-control", id = "BrandID" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SingleProduct.BrandIdFk, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SingleProduct.Ram, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-sm-3 col-md-3 control-label" })
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SingleProduct.Ram, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SingleProduct.Ram, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SingleProduct.Processor, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-sm-3 col-md-3 control-label" })
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SingleProduct.Processor, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SingleProduct.Processor, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-group">
                    @Html.Label("CONDITION", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-sm-3 col-md-3 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SingleProduct.Conditon, selectList, "CHOOSE CONDITION", new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SingleProduct.Conditon, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SingleProduct.Location, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-sm-3 col-md-3 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SingleProduct.Location, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SingleProduct.Location, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SingleProduct.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-sm-3 col-md-3 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.SingleProduct.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SingleProduct.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="image-gallery-wrapper">
    <div class="img-gallery">
        @if (Model.ImageList.Any())
        {
            foreach (var item in Model.ImageList)
            {
                <div class="img-wrapper">
                    <p>Image 1</p>
                    <div class="img-box">
                        <input type="file" name="thumb" value="" class="file-style" onchange="readURL(this)" ; />
                        <img src="/Content/Assets/Photos/Thumbs/@item.ImageName" alt="your image" id="imgName" value="@item.ImageName" />
                        <button id="RemoveImage">Remove Image</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            }
        }

    </div>        
</div>
<div class="text-center">
    <button type="submit" class="roundSubmitBtn" style="background:#7048f0 !important;font-size:14px !important; margin-top:40px;">SUMBIT <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
</div>
}
```

As i added my code i am getting null exception error.but i have a check of null or not so why i am getting this null object reference error.
and i have also tried Count() and !=null in IF statement.i am getting erro while i submit form and error is null exception error so tell me where i am wrong

Comment: Related issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it. Check the contents of `ImageList` first.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto data is displaying from imagelist but when i submit form then get a null exception

Comment: You're showing the GET action but still not showing the POST action, can you provide it too? If you want to submit the form you need to use textboxes or hidden fields containing image path together with other data you want to manipulate into POST action.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto so kindly review question

Comment: And where exactly does the error occur? Would be nice to know.

Comment: @Marco yeah ...  if (Model.ImageList.Any()) error occured there. when i submit form

Comment: Is that the exception occurred *before* or *after* submitting the form? If the exception shown after submit, then your return statement from POST method should be inspected.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto exception occurred after submitting form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By inspecting POST action method provided in question, the problem seem coming from `return View()` statement which returns same view page as in GET action method but without returning viewmodel class instance, which causing `ProductViewModel.ImageList` contains null value.

The brief code below shows the problem:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditProduct(Prouduct product, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> thumb, ImageGallery images)
{
    CategoryDropdown();
    BrandDropdown();
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {       
       // image processing and saving to DB
    }

    // the view returned without viewmodel
    // this will trigger NullReferenceException because ProductViewModel.ImageList is not reassigned yet
    return View();
}
```

Therefore, you should reassign `ProductViewModel.ImageList` property after saving posted data into database, and return the same view together with new `ProductViewModel` instance (or redirect to another action if necessary by following PRG pattern with `RedirectToAction`):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditProduct(Prouduct product, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> thumb, ImageGallery images)
{
    CategoryDropdown();
    BrandDropdown();
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {       
       // image processing and saving to DB
    }

    // create viewmodel instance
    var ViewModel = new ProductViewModel();         

    ViewModel.ImageList = ...; // reassign ImageList property here
    return View(ViewModel);
}
```